# Why can string that is a reference type be a non-null const while other reference type consts must be null?

Tags: c#

As far as I know, `string` is a reference type. `const` can be used with `reference` type only if they are assigned `null`. My question is that

why can `string` which is a reference type can be assigned a literal string (or non-null)?

Comment: `const` means that cannot change and we know `String` are **immutable**

Comment: you are confusing `const` and `ReadOnly`

Comment: @Franck: Unfortunately, no. I know `readonly` for runtime evaluation.

Comment: Well, string is only a reference type for performance reasons. In practice, it works more like a value type - it's immutable, and the reference is unimportant. So in a way, it's a value type, which is always passed around as a reference. I expect that if you could ensure immutability in other reference types (in compile-time!) it would be possible to use them as `const`s as well - in other words, they really would be value types (made up exclusively of other value types), but with reference passing semantics.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Taken from the [const](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) documentation:

> A constant expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile time. Therefore, the only possible values for constants of reference types are string and a null reference.

In other words, it's an exception. Life would be a whole lot more difficult if there weren't such things as string constants.

You can also remember that it's not *all* strings, for instance you can't compile with the code `const string test = new string('t', 7);`, even though you could with `static string test = new string('t', 7);`. On the other hand, while you can define a string constant as a string literal (`test = "value";`), you can't define any other reference types with a literal (`Form f = ???`).

Answer (score 4):

This is a special rule in the C# language and a feature of the CLR. The compiler knows how to embed strings into the assembly meta-data.

Answer (score 3):

ECMA-334 C# Specification has the following note (emphasis mine):

> As described in §14.16, a constant-expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compiletime.
>   Since the only way to create a non-null value of a reference-type other than string is to apply the
>   new operator, and since the new operator is not permitted in a constant-expression, the only possible value
>   for constants of reference-types **other than string** is null.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx):

> Constants can be numbers, Boolean values, **strings**, or a null reference.

Comment: No. I didn't say that `const` only for reference type.

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014 fair enough, fixed my answer.

Comment: `char`s and enums can be constants as well.

Comment: @AlexD true and at the same time both are essentially 'numbers' in .NET

Answer (score 0):

Each assembly contains a sequence of bytes which comprise all the strings that are defined within the assembly, and when the type is loaded the system will create a list of new string objects using the bytes in that sequence.  Each string literal declared within the assembly is assigned an index, and an instruction to load a string literal reads the string object from the table of string objects that were created when that assembly was loaded.

Such behavior would be possible with any class type which does not contain any nested class-type fields, but would generally only be useful with immutable class types.  Since there is no general means of distinguishing immutable class types, especially given that the possibility that assemblies might be loaded with "unusual" definitions for types like e.g. `Tuple<int, int>`, the behavior is limited to the one class type which meets that criterion and cannot be made to do otherwise: `System.String`.